# Is an investment where I receive returns for a period of time halal?

Tags: halal-haram, finance, investment

I recently made an investment but now am uncertain if the returns are halal.  Below is the agreement between me and the company.

1. I invested a sum of money for a project in India and have a stake in a portion of the land based on the amount I invested.
2. Each month, I will receive 3.5% returns for duration of 60 months. This figure may change at the discretion of the company.
3. In the event the project fails, I will stop getting my returns but will get any shortfall of my invested capital once the land is sold. (I will not get anything further if the company is unable to sell the land which I have a stake in)

May I know if this arrangement is halal?

Answer (score -1):

What is the **currency** used for your transaction, US$, Singapour$ or India rupee? This makes a big difference.

**What about return?** 3.5% for 12 months is 42% per year.
If someone would promise me this kind of return, I would think it is a scam.

**Is it halal?** 
The description you give on this agreement makes me think it is speculation or Haram.